# Why all libraries are using `declare var`

Tags: typescript

I am wondering why every lib I see is using `declare var` syntax instead of `declare const`. For example lib.d.ts:

```
declare var statusbar: BarProp;
declare var styleMedia: StyleMedia;
declare var toolbar: BarProp;
declare var top: Window;
declare var window: Window;
```

why not

```
declare const statusbar: BarProp;
declare const styleMedia: StyleMedia;
declare const toolbar: BarProp;
declare const top: Window;
declare const window: Window;
```

to be sure that there is no code which can override `window` with something else? I am using `declare const` in my `ts` files and it is working very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most library definitions were written before `const` was added (TypeScript 1.4). It may also be waiting to catch on with library definition authors.

It is worth bearing in mind that you should only use `const` honestly in a definition file - because you are preventing people overwriting the value in their code.

Strictly speaking you should only match a `const` definition with a constant value in ECMAScript - otherwise you are defining your opinion of the code rather than the actual implementation. If someone wanted to override a variable from a library, and the library authors allow it - it would be incorrect of the definition file to prevent it; even if you don't think people should be allowed to do it.

Where the value cannot be overwritten, `const` is the correct way of declaring the immutability in a type definition.

Comment: Can't agree with `TS1.4` argument because `DefenitlyTyped` is using this notation too regardless they are using TS2.1 syntax in theirs definition files.

Comment: Yes - and we have 1,000s of definition files to manage, many of which were created when TypeScript was v0.8. While we update them to keep them "building" and to reflect changes in the libraries they represent, it is a mammoth job to rewrite them to take into account every syntax change.